# MySQL insert query - FLASK

Tags: python, mysql, flask

```
query="""insert into serial_ids values (%s,%s)"""
cur.execute(query, (serial,model))
```

I am using MySQL in Flask framework but I dont see the row inserted. The same code piece is working with python (no framework).

Also, is there any way to do autocommit true in Flask or some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit the transaction, with `con.commit()`, where `con` is your connection.

Have a read through the [documentation for SQLAlchemy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlalchemy/) - using sqlalchemy will automatically commit the transactions.

Comment: thanks burhan, I did the split of instantiating cursor and did the commit. Although thanks for the link. will look into it.